# How to know which of my fonts do or don't support certain glyphs?

Tags: fonts, windows, glyphs, monospace

I have a long list of glyphs with various Unicode points across **several *Unicode blocks*** that I need to represent in a monospaced form *(which mean with a single font)*. How I can know which glyph the font does not support in that list?

I tried Microsoft Word, Open Office, Notepad++ and some others, but even ᴡindows® Notepad [tries to substitute](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=91541#c1) unknown characters from glyphs in other fonts instead of using the replacement character directly. Sometimes it even substitute characters whereas they exist in the font

Opening a font editor and checking Unicode points one by one would definitely takes hours.
Below is the text I need to display properly

```
┌─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┲━━━━━━━━━┓ ┏━━━━━┱─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ ɶ   │     │ É   │     │     │     │     │ È   │     │     │ À   │ № № │     ┃         ┃ ┃ Ver ┃     │     │     │
│ 　   │    │     │     │     │    │     │Espac│     │     │     │ № № │     ┃      ‎  ┃ ┃Num ⌓┃ ⁄ ⨸ │ ⋇ ⨉ │ ₋ ₋ │
┢━━━━━┷━┱───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┴─┬───┺━┳━━━━━━━┫ ┡━━━━━╃─────┼─────┼─────┤
┃⁮       ┃ ᴀ   │ ᴢ   │ ᴇ ℯ │ ʀ ℝ │ ᴛ   │ ʏ   │ ᴜ   │ ɪ  │ ᴏ ℴ │ ᴘ ℘ │     │     ┃Entrée ┃ │ ⁷   │ ⁸   │ ⁹   │     │
┃ ⁯    ⁯  ┃    │    │ ℯ ℰ │  ℛ │    │    │    │\t ℐ │ ℴ ℴ │  ℘ │    │     ┃   ⏎   ┃ │ ⁷   │ ⁸   │ ⁹   │     │
┣━━━━━━━┻┱────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┴┬────┺┓      ┃ ├─────┼─────┼─────┤     │
┃        ┃ ᴁ   │ ꜱ   │ ᴅ   │ ꜰ ℉ │ ɢ   │ ʜ   │ ᴊ   │ ᴋ → │ ʟ ℓ │ ᴍ ℳ │ Ù   │     ┃      ┃ │ ⁴   │ ⁵   │ ⁶   │     │
┃ꜱɢᴀᴘ ⇬  ┃    │    │    │  ℱ │ ℊ ℊ │  ℋ │ \n  │    │ ℓ ℒ │ \r  │     │     ┃      ┃ │ ⁴   │ ⁵   │ ⁶   │ ₊ ₊ │
┣━━━━━━━┳┹────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┬┴────┲┷━━━━━┻━━━━━━┫ ├─────┼─────┼─────┼─────┤
┃       ┃     │ ᴡ   │ ꭥ   │ ᴄ ℃ │ ᴠ   │ ʙ ℬ │ ɴ   │     │     │     │     ┃             ┃ │ ¹   │ ²   │ ³   │     │
┃Shift ⇧┃     │    │    │    │   │  ℬ │    │     │     │     │     ┃Shift ⇧      ┃ │ ¹   │ ²   │ ³   │ Ent │
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━┷━┳━━━┷━━━┱─┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴───┲━┷━━━━━╈━━━━━┻━┳━━━━━━━┳━━━┛ ├─────┴─────┼─────┤  ⏎  │
┃       ┃       ┃       ┃                                   ┃       ┃       ┃       ┃     │ ⁰         │     │     │
┃Ctrl   ┃Meta   ┃Alt    ┃                                   ┃AltGr ⇮┃Menu   ┃Ctrl   ┃     │ ⁰         │ ,   │     │
┗━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┹───────────────────────────────────┺━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┻━━━━━━━┛     └───────────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Comment: Are you familiar with basic command line operations?  The [Adobe Font Development Kit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/opentype/afdko.html) comes with `ttx`, and a line `ttx -t cmap times.ttf` creates a file containing all of its glyphs and their encodings.

Comment: @Jongware Which is not free.

Comment: It isn't? I just downloaded it from the Adobe site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I learnt about a new tool, which "was made just for your question". It was published in 2011 but I am sharing it here, less than one hour after I tested it:

http://blog.tavultesoft.com/2011/07/character-identifier-tool.html

Hope this helps, it is an .exe so will probably need Windows.

Comment: A nicer solution than using a font too large for the ꜱꜰɴᴛ format *(which what I did)*.

Answer (score 2):

I know your problem, because I am working for a minority language.

You could go to myfonts.com and look under "languages" if your language or project is maybe covered. This would be the easy answer, find the right language and the filter will find all fonts which carry your characters.

---

If you have special needs, or characters which are not "language related" but rather something "technical", you can go to advanced search and enter your own(!) sample-text (maybe just your tricky characters (but I would enter some letters too, to get a feel for the design of the fonts)) in the sample-text-box top left.

You will see many fonts and can scroll down to find those who can render your characters. You can limit the list, if you know roughly what you need (for example monospace); by using the provided powerful search tools.

If you have your own short-list of fonts (which you own, or whatever) then even better, just search for those, and see what characters come up properly.

I always like using Arial Unicode as a reference, because it has got all the characters we need. So I can check for example that my sample text has been properly copied and pasted.

Once you click on a promissing font, you will see symbols about glyph-coverage as explained in their online help under FAQ and Language Support.

---

If you only want to check on the fonts which are already installed on your machine, you can get a free tool here: http://www.screamfactor.de/

It is only in German(?) but should be fairly easy. You can set your own sample text and so can quickly check, which fonts are supporting your tricky characters.

You can also search for "free font managers" if you do not like this one; I believe a font manager is the best solution if you are forced to work with special characters a lot. I found another one, which is also free and does English too:  http://us.fontviewer.de/

Comment: The problem is that some blocks are symbols which aren't used by any language.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer above to make clearer: filtering by language is the easy option. If you got special needs, you can enter your own sample-text (including your symbols) and then you can quickly see, which fonts carry your symbols - all the other fonts will just show a box (unlike what your editors do, where you have to look twice which is a genuine character and which is an (unwanted) replacement from another font).

Comment: what I really need is to find the installed font which support all the characters of my list.

Comment: I designed a bitmap font.

Comment: If you believe that one (or more) of your installed fonts has got all the characters in your list, you could best use a "font manager". That was the second part of my answer above. I have proposed two free font managers to you. Did you try any of these?

Comment: I finally created a monospace [svg font](http://ytrezq.sdfeu.org/Outils/table%20de%20caractères) which contain every assigned unicode points, based on ɢɴᴜ unifont. I created a pcf one for my own desktop usage as well.