# How to find/browse fonts that include certain rare characters? (unicode/international)

Tags: fonts, unicode

This question is similar to [How to know which of my fonts do or don't support certain glyphs?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/57518/how-to-know-which-of-my-fonts-do-or-dont-support-certain-glyphs/58098#58098), but for fonts in font shops, not just fonts I already have.

I need to make a design which includes two relatively rare international characters - **ɔ** and **ɛ**:

[image]

The vast majority of fonts don't support these characters. Arial does, and Arial Bold, but that's all I've found so far.

What I'd like to do, is find some font store or similar that lets me input the characters I need, and filters out fonts that don't include those characters, leaving me able to browse, choose between and hopefully buy from the few that do.

Does any such service or tool exist?

---

The above linked question has an answer **suggesting going to https://www.myfonts.com/languages/ and choosing the appropriate language**. Unfortunately, their languages list is, as they put it, a...

> ### Work in progress
>
> We realize this page is very sparse at the moment. We’re working on it!

...and the 15 options don't match my needs (those two characters are from Sierra Leoneon Krio, it'll be a while before that's added to their list!). So I really do need to search by *character*, not *language*.

That said, browsing their ["IPA/Phonetic" fonts](https://www.myfonts.com/search/charset%3Aphon) did turn up an amazing 13 fonts matching my characters, out of 43 (I guess if a font covers IPA, it might well cover *everything*). It's better than anything else I've tried, but it's not the filter I'm looking for.

---

It also suggests putting in the text as sample text then scrolling down until something can handle it. This helped with something like the IPA filter but for any other results set, I was literally scrolling past hundreds and hundreds before finding a single match.

Comment: These two should appear in all IPA fonts as these are well-established *phonetic* characters,  but (1) IPA does not define capitals, and (2) common use characters appear outside the IPA range - and then usually in combination with a capital alternative. If on Windows, check your set of C-fonts, as they are amazingly up to date.

Comment: @Jongware’s point is an important one: both these characters are exceedingly common in phonetic writing (they represent the o sound in _thought_ [as said in the Northwest of the US] and the e sound in _let_), but if you need to use them for something like writing in [Kabiyè](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabye_language), you'll need capital Ɔ and Ɛ as well (plus quite a few more), since those are part of the standard Kabiyè orthography.

Comment: (Just checked: these Windows standard fonts contain Ɔ Ɛ ɔ ɛ: Times New Roman, Arial, Courier (!), Tahoma, Segoe UI, as well as some of the C-fonts I referred to: Calibri, Consolas, and Cambria.)

Comment: @Jongware Ah, I didn't know that was what you meant by "C-fonts". If you put that list as an additional answer it'll definitely deserve an upvote or two.

Comment: Nah – I briefly considered doing so but even though I have a couple of solutions (frequently necessary as I work with lots of texts on linguistics), they all are exclusively for "local" fonts, and would not work to search on external sites.

Comment: As an additional, tangential note on local fonts, the Character Palette in OS X makes this easy to do for local fonts as well: just type/copy-paste the character you want into the search field (or select it in the palette in some other way), and the Font Variation section on the right will show you that character in all currently installed fonts that contain it. Click on an individual character there to see which font it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[myfonts.com](http://www.myfonts.com) does indeed provide one solution. In the advanced search form, select “available characters” from the field to search, “contains,” and type your character in the search box.  Be sure to check the results by looking at the table of glyphs in each font, because I haven’t found the results absolutely reliable, but they do give you a start.

Where is the advanced search form?  As on many sites, it shows up only after you do an ordinary search.  Silly design, in my opinion, but there it is.

Comment: Brilliant! About half the results contain my character, which is the best yet - don't know why some results don't but this seems to be a way to see every don't that matches (or at least, most)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore, unfortunately. I couldn't find the advanced search after doing an ordinary search. Under https://www.myfonts.com/search/ there are filters, but they don't seemm to include "available characters".

Comment: @joriki Yes, lots of useful features on the site have vanished. It seems that, in its efforts to make the site easier to browse on phones, Monotype has impoverished the experience on desktops. I’ve complained; join the chorus, and perhaps Monotype will pay attention?

Comment: Once again we see that mobile sucks.

Answer (score 5):

## The website fontspace.com

The website fontspace.com seems to have this feature, when combined with google. For example, let's say you want to find fonts that have the musical character

*(Hopefully as you're reading this, your system fonts can display the example character)*

1. Open Google and search for `site:fontspace.com`
2. Click on the first result entitled [musical symbol right repeat sign u+1d107 - FontSpace](https://www.fontspace.com/unicode/char/1D107-musical-symbol-right-repeat-sign)
3. Scroll down the page to see a list of fonts that contain this Unicode character:
   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Wow, what a great site! For my test character, it returned over 200 fonts, compared to about 10 from FileFormat.info. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same characters (for Sierra Leonean Krio and Themne, in fact!). Here is what I ended up with after a fair bit of research.

*Noto*
https://www.google.com/get/noto/

*Gentium plus*
https://software.sil.org/gentium/

*Junicode*
https://junicode.sourceforge.io/

It's frustrating that some fonts include the characters I need but just appear to use a duplicate of the Arial character. This can look really bad...
[image: character styling is not always consistent.]

The ones that I linked to above, do seem to have consistent styling, atleast from what I've seen so far. I worked through this partially using the following resource:
https://r12a.github.io/scripts/fontlist/?script=latn&text=%C3%A1%20%C3%A3%20%C3%A9%20%C3%AD%20%C3%B3%20%C3%B5%20%C3%BA%20%C3%81%20%C3%83%20%C3%89%20%C3%8D%20%C3%93%20%C3%95%20%C3%9A%20%C6%81%20%C6%8A%20%C6%90%20%C6%86%20%C4%A9%20%C5%8B%20%C5%A9%20%C4%A8%20%C5%8A%20%C5%A8%20%E1%BA%BD%20%E1%BA%BC%20%C9%93%20%C9%97%20%C9%9B%20%C9%94%20%CC%81%20%CC%83#result

Answer (score 2):

Meanwhile, myfonts.com seems to have stopped offering the "available characters" search option.

However, [FileFormat.Info](https://www.fileformat.info/) has a solution:

1. Navigate to https://www.fileformat.info/.
2. Paste the character in the search bar. Alternatively, enter its unicode name or code point.
3. Submit the form and navigate to the character reference page listed in the search results:

   - [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN O' (U+0254)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0254/index.htm)
   - [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E' (U+025B)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/025b/index.htm)
4. Click the link to the right of the character rendering labelled "Fonts that support U+...". On the subsequent page, you'll find a table of font names and links to a preview rendering that looks like this:

   [image: Table]

   - [LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN O (U+0254) Font Support](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0254/fontsupport.htm)
   - [LATIN SMALL LETTER OPEN E (U+025B) Font Support](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/025b/fontsupport.htm)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

[Noto Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Noto+Sans) aims to cover all of Unicode Characters. Not there yet, but seems to have both that you're looking for.

Comment: OP was not looking for a single particular font, but for a way to find "fonts in font shops".

Comment: True, this does not address the question directly, but I thought it might be useful, not only to the OP, but to others looking for a font that will, at least at some point, support all encoded characters.

Comment: Post a comment then. This is not an answer.